# Exception handling in a dll

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a method in **dll**

```
    private static void SaveXmlStringToXmlFile(string xmlString, string xmlFileFullPath)
    {
        XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Save(xmlFileFullPath);
    }
```

I know that `Parse` and `Save` can throw several exceptions. Anyway I have no idea how to handle these exceptions because it's a dll.

Put a `try/catch throw;` around the code. Isn't this redundant to the present code?

What's the best practice?

**EDIT:** Let's assume the user of the dll doen't have any influence on what `xmlString` could be.

Comment: As it often happens.. it depends. 
Personally, not knowing all the other details, I would just let the function throw, document it, and let the caller deal with the exception(s)

Comment: Is `SaveXmlStringToXmlFile` in a DLL or just `Parse` and `Save`?

Comment: I think he means [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) and similarly for save. To OP, I think you'll struggle to find a best practice as it depends on your application a little bit, as to how much this functionality is depended on and what input the user can define

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis SaveXmlStringToXmlFile is in the dll and save and parse are the methods of XDocument

Comment: Would a user of your library be surprised to see an `XmlException` or `IOException` thrown at them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no particular distinction between code that's in another assembly (such as a DLL) and code that's in your entry assembly, when it comes to exceptions.

You should put the try/catch for each exception exactly where there is enough information to handle that exception (and recover from it, if it's something you want to do). As with any other exception, you should reason about this based on the type of the exception and the nesting level it can be thrown from, not the assembly where it originates from.

The rule of thumb I typically use is this: If `SaveXmlStringToXmlFile` fails, should its caller continue like nothing happened? If not (that is, if the following statements in the caller should be abandoned), then don't put the try/catch in `SaveXmlStringToXmlFile`, but higher.